# HTTP POST requests from Android switching between two access points

Tags: android, networking, routes, network-programming

I have a two access points and one main router in the same network. A server and two access points are connected to a switch (hub) and this switch is connected to main router. When I connect my Android device to access point 2 and send a request (HTTP POST) to the server and connect (automatically switch between two access point when out of range for other) device to access point 1 it makes the same processes twice.

When I send a package ACK, it comes back to ap2 and times out. And the client sends the package again.

Is there any way to solve this problem like sending an ACK back to two access points at once? Or perhaps the problem may be occurring because of something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to solve it. You must solve it in the application layer by implementing a mechanism to make the operation **idempotent**. To begin, the problem seems to be as you described it.

To make the operation idempotent you can include a counter in the message. The client increments the counter for every different message it sends. On the server side, if it receives a message with a repeated counter value, it knows the message is a dup and it just drops it. You can come up with some corner cases I might overlook but essentially this is how you should solve it.